# Not able to login after encrypting the username

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, encryption

I have 2 fields username and password, while registering the user I am encrypting the username with AES and store into database, now I am unable to login because the plain text is not matching with encrypted data.

How can I resolve this problem?

P.s.-
1)I am using Crypto.js library
2)While login I can't again encrypt the username again as it is giving different encrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is usually done with a hash. A hash function of the username will always return the same hash value.

If there is a specific reason for  encrypting the username rather than hashing (which you haven’t explained though), then you will need to decrypt it in order to compare the values *or* use an encryption mode that is *deterministic* and does not involve a random initialization vector. See [this question and its answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42642/134095) for details.

Answer (score 0):

On your login logic, you should use the same AES encryption to encrypt the user 's input username during their login.
If the username is actually in your database, using that encrypted username should be able to query/locate the username in your database.

Below are for your reference on how the encrypt and decrypt works (copied from [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)):

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
 
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123').toString();
 
// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 
console.log(originalText); // 'my message'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response,
The Register and login API are different. So when I am encrypting the username with same logic during the login, then I am getting different encrypted data(It is because of some randomness in AES algorithm)

Comment: Perhaps you could use a secret key like the "encrypt code" I have mentioned in my reply. 
Using a consistent key should able to generate the same encrypted text/data.

Comment: Yes I used the same secret key but getting different encrypted data